# include does not work in a template on live instance in django 1.11

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, include

I work with django 1.11 and I have a problem with `include` at base.html.

When I work on localhost - everything is OK. The problem starts when the code goes live, on the server.

The problem is here:

```
{% include "pages/menu.html" %}
```

**EDIT:**

```
    ----project/
    ----templates/
    --------pages/
    ------------footer.html
    --------base.html
```

Comment: Where is base.html located? Is it at the root of your app or the root of the projects?

Comment: @polarise please check my edit

Comment: Check template dirs config please

Comment: You don't seem to have said what the problem is. What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have a misconfiguration in your project.

There are two places you can place templates:

1. In the app

   `my_project/my_app/templates/my_app/menu.html`
2. In the global templates

   `my_project/templates/menu.html`

It is not clear which of these you're using.

Furthermore, in production you will need to have `my_project/templates` located in the root of your webserver root. So, for Apache this might be something like `/var/www/my_project/templates` which a declaration in the Apache configs that this is where it should search for global templates.